# SQL Null Data Canceling Out All of Calculation

Tags: sql

I have this calculation/query here:

```
SELECT  u.username,
        (a.totalCount * 7) +
        (b.totalCount * 3) +
        (c.totalCount * 1) AS totalScore
        FROM users u 
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
                FROM items 
                GROUP BY user_id
            ) a ON a.user_id= u.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
                FROM comments
                GROUP BY user_id
            ) b ON b.user_id= u.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
                FROM ratings
                GROUP BY user_id
            ) c ON c.user_id = u.user_id

        ORDER BY totalScore DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The problem is, if either a,b, or c returns 0, the entire `totalScore` is 0.  I can't figure out what is going on?  I am not multiplying the final tally by 0 I don't think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's rather a null problem (with your LEFT JOIN, this might easily happen).

And `NULL + 1 + 2 = NULL`

So use the `COALESCE` (if null then...) operator

so

```
SELECT  u.username,
        (COALESCE(a.totalCount, 0) * 7) +
        (COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) * 3) +
        (COALESCE(c.totalCount, 0) * 1) AS totalScore
```

and a little [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/6583)